# bs4 search a word in all attributes of a given tag

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was developing a web scraper to find the price tag from a given website.

I have a code

```
price = soup.findAll(['div'],{'class':re.compile(r'(.*?price.*?)',re.IGNORECASE)})
```

With this, I was able to find all div tags with a class attribute having values with a price keyword. (words which contain price like - data-price, price value etc.)

But I want to retrieve all div tags which contain price keyword irrespective of the attribute name.

Example:

The Website I am trying to scrape has this format:

```
<div class="css-2vqe5n esdkp3p0" data-automation="buybox-price" aria-label="Now $74">$74</div>
```

My code only retrieves if the price keyword is present in the class attribute, But in this case, it is present in the data-automation attribute.

So I am looking for a solution that would search all attributes of the div tag but not only in the class tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this task you can use `.find_all()` with custom function.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = '''
<div class="css-2vqe5n esdkp3p0" data-automation="buybox-price" aria-label="Now $74">$74</div>
<div class="price value" aria-label="Now $75">$75</div>
<div class="discount-price" aria-label="Now $76">$76</div>
<div class="something_other">other</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

def is_price(tag):
    for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
        if 'price' in v:
            return True
        elif isinstance(v, list) and any('price' in i for i in v):
            return True


for tag in soup.find_all(is_price):
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```
<div aria-label="Now $74" class="css-2vqe5n esdkp3p0" data-automation="buybox-price">$74</div>
<div aria-label="Now $75" class="price value">$75</div>
<div aria-label="Now $76" class="discount-price">$76</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed exactly!